# Table view showing empty

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I basically want to create a custom view and add a tableview into it. I'm able to do that successfully and the tableview is also displayed properly when I run the code. But the tablview is showing empty inspite of having registered the custom tablview cell in `viewDidLoad`. It is a custom tableview cell that I have designed to be loaded in the tablview.

The .swift file of the custom view class that I have made looks like so...

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TagResolutionView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var tagResolutionView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableview: UITableView!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
      }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

       @IBOutlet weak var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
           get {
               return tableview.delegate
           }
           set {
               tableview.delegate = newValue
           }
       }

       @IBOutlet weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
           get {
               return tableview.dataSource
           }
           set {
               tableview.dataSource = newValue
           }
       }

    func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        tableview.register(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass")
    }

    func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell? {
        return tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TagResolutionView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(tagResolutionView)

        tagResolutionView.frame = self.bounds

        tagResolutionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

    }
}
```

This is how I have set the tableview in my main viewcontroller...

In `viewDidLoad`,

```
   standardsProceduresView.delegate = self
    standardsProceduresView.dataSource = self



   standardsProceduresView.registerClass(cellClass: UpdatingListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass")
```

And further,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell: UpdatingListTableViewCell = self.standardsProceduresView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: "cellClass") as! UpdatingListTableViewCell

    cell.nameLbl.text = "MyName" //But here I get a crash saying 'Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value'
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That crash tells you there is something wrong with the dequeueing of cells or the casting of that cell to the given class. Maybe do these one after another and add a breakpoint (or print) to see what the result is of the dequeue before the cast:

```
let cell = self.standardsProceduresView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: "cellClass")
print(cell)
let updatingCell = cell as! UpdatingListTableViewCell
```

I can also see that you set the `dataSource` before you register the class, which may lead to problems. Try to register the class first before you set the `dataSource`.

Comment: Thanks @vrwim..the issue was that I didn't register the nib..

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't register the nib...

Instead of this..

```
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {
        tableview.register(cellClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass")
    }
```

I had to write this...

```
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) {

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "UpdatingListTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        tableview.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellClass")
    }
```